# How to open reference page view in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, simulator

I want to know how to open the visible page view in Xcode.

For example, I have a viewController named TransactionDetailViewController, and suppose I'm currently on a code editing page. Is there a way to get me to the corresponding visualization TransactionDetailViewController page from the current code page?

Answer (score 0):

You can't preview before compile.
You can run it, and use debug view hierarchy to see TransactionDetailViewController.

https://static.packt-cdn.com/products/9781786461698/graphics/image_09_007.png